# Angular Date Pipe displays wrong time?

Tags: sql-server, angular

Here is a simple line of code I am using:

```
<td style="text-align: center;"> {{ item.StartAt | date:"HH:MM"}}</td>
```

The data is fetched from database which has a DateTime column. Data is in object form so that I can convert date time to time. Without the Date pipe, the received value on the website is:

```
1900-01-01T10:00:00.000Z
```

But with the date pipe, the time received is:

```
14:01
```

As you can see there is a difference of 4 hours and 1 minute time. Can someone please tell how can I get exact time? Thank you.

Comment: The ISO date ends with a `Z` so it's a UTC date. Angular's date pipe takes into account the time zone. Depending on what time zone you are, this could explain the 4 hours offset, but not the 1 minute...

Comment: I have used ```Z``` but it only displays the timezone, not adjust the datetime according to the timezone. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of ISO 8601 dates and time zones. But your question lacks details. Are you sure that the date you store in the database is correct, and if not, what do you store and how? What time zone are you in?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the problem by fetching **Time** instead of **DateTime** in Stored Procedure of Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

Since Date Pipes have an issue of Timezone in Angular, I went to the database (SQL Server) and there I changed the Stored Procedure to fetch only Time instead of DateTime using `convert(varchar, sd.StartAt, 24)`. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

capital "M" is month , you need to have

```
<td style="text-align: center;"> {{ item.StartAt | date:"HH:mm"}}</td>
```